# Curl exec returns more than JSON. How do I extract just the JSON data?

Tags: php, json, curl

My curl exec response returns this:

`string(151937) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept-Tenant, Authorization Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,OPTIONS Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Cache-Control: private Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Date: Mon, 28 Sep 2015 08:35:33 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Warning: Unsupported Authentication Scheme X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Content-Length: 151475 Connection: keep-alive {"ShortResultText":"SE19","Restaurants":[{"Id":50371,"Name":"Mahjestics Caribbean Cuisine","Address":"247 Gypsy Road","Postcode":"SE27 9QY","City":"London","CuisineTypes":[{"Id":76,"Name":"Caribbean","SeoName":null},{"Id":97,"Name":"African","SeoName":null}],"Url":"http://majestic-caribbean-cuisine-west-norwood.just-` ...

But the JSON starts here at "{ ShortResultText"..:

```
{
    "ShortResultText": "SE19",
    "Restaurants": [
        {
            "Id": 50371,
            "Name": "Mahjestics Caribbean Cuisine",
            "Address": "247 Gypsy Road",
            "Postcode": "SE27 9QY",
            "City": "London",
            "CuisineTypes": [
                {
                    "Id": 76,
                    "Name": "Caribbean",
                    "SeoName": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 97,
                    "Name": "African",
                    "SeoName": null
                }
"Url": "http://majestic-caribbean-cuisine-west-norwood.test.co.uk",
            "IsOpenNow": true,
            "IsSponsored": false,
            "IsNew": false,
            "IsTemporarilyOffline": false,
            "ReasonWhyTemporarilyOffline": "",
            "UniqueName": "majestic-caribbean-cuisine-west-norwood",
            "IsCloseBy": false,
            "IsHalal": true,
            "DefaultDisplayRank": 1,
            "IsOpenNowForDelivery": true,
            "IsOpenNowForCollection": true,
            "RatingStars": 4.71,
            "Logo": [
                {
                    "StandardResolutionURL": "http://d30v2pzvrfyzpo.cloudfront.net/uk/images/restaurants/50371.gif"
                }
            ],
            "Deals": [],
            "NumberOfRatings": 7
```

I need to get JUST the JSON data from my curl response and I'm not sure the best way to go about it? The curl response header might vary in length depending on the "ShortResultText" value from POST as this is a variable.

Then I'll be able to get the data in an array and loop through it.

Curl code:

```
$url = "http://api-interview.test.com/restaurants?q=se19";
$ch = curl_init();

$api_headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'Accept-Tenant: uk',
    'Accept-Language: en-GB',
    'Authorization: Basic VGVjaFRlc3RBUEk6dXNlcjI=',
    'Host: api-interview.test.com'
    );

//print_r($api_headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $api_headers);


// echo "<pre>";
// $data = curl_exec($ch);
// echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";

$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo "</pre>";

//just testing here
//    $json = json_encode($data, true);
//    $json1 = json_decode($json, true);
//    var_dump($json1);

//print $json1['restaurants'];

//$json = json_encode($data, true);

// foreach($json['restaurants'] as $value) {
//  echo $value->postcode;
// }
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Can i see your curl code?

Comment: I just updated my post.

Comment: What do you want to get for example?

Comment: Name, CusineTypes and RatingStars

Comment: Your json is wrong. Try to test here. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I already have. I deleted everything before "{"ShortResultText.." and it ran fine. Which is why I'm asking how to get rid of all the headers before because it seems like the JSON is included IN the header itself.

Comment: Is that All the JSON?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90776/discussion-between-growthmindset-and-aldrin27).

Comment: Sorry the discussion tab is blocked in my end. Is that all the JSON?

Comment: Not all the JSON no, I cut much of it out because there are about 8000 rows.

Comment: I will post my answer. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to false.

Comment: I think the problem is that the JSON is being returned with the header. Because if I set that to false nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json1 = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($json1['Restaurants'] as $key => $val){
 print_r($val); // You will get here the ID, Name ....

  echo 'ID: ' $val['Id'] . 'Name: ' . $val['Name']; . 'Rating Stars: ' . $val['RatingStars']..

   //If you want to go deeper and get the CuisineTypes just do below 
   foreach($val['CuisineTypes'] as $key2 => $val2) {
     print_r($val2); //This is the cuisine types

   }
}
```

Or you can just manipulate your array:

```
$newData = [];

foreach($json1['Restaurants'] as $key => $val)
{
  $newData[] = ['Name' => $val['Name'], 'CusineTypes' => $val['CuisineTypes'], 'RatingStars' => $val['RatingStars']];
}
  print_r($newData);
```

Comment: Ahh but the issue is the variable $json doesn't have the json in it. I don't know how to separate the valid JSON from the headers.